# How to retrieve correct filesystem metrics in C for UBIFS filesystem with on-the-fly data compression enabled?

Tags: c, filesystems, compression, ubifs

**Context**

I am using UBIFS filesystem with on-the-fly data compression enabled. I need to get correct filesystem metrics (total, used, free space) in a C code.

**What was tried**

I used `statvfs` call to retrieve the metrics successfully but noticed that values returned were as if data was never compressed. After doing `sync(8)` call from command line and calling the C code again, correct values were returned so in C code I included call to `sync(2)` right before `statvfs`. Calling modified C code again still returned metrics with values as if data was not compressed. Then I tried to make a system call `system("sync")` before `statvfs` but still incorrect metric values were returned. Only after waiting like 10 seconds or by explicit `sync(8)` call the returned filesystem metrics were correct.

**Questions**

1) Why there is this difference between call to `sync(2)` or `system("sync")` in C code right before `statvfs` and `sync(8)` call from command line?

2) How to commit pending/cached data to disk in C code so that consequent `statvfs` call would return correct filesystem metrics?